# What is the maximum number of triangles in a planar graph with n vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, triangles, planar-graphs

The answer is obvious for small numbers of nodes:
$$n<3: 0\\
n=3: 1\\
n=4: 3\\
n=5: 5  (see below)$$

[image]

Comment: If you go from one graph to the next one by adding a new vertex inside one of the triangles already there and drawing a line to each of the vertices of that triangle, you get three new triangles. So your number increases by _at least_ $3$ from one $n$ to the next. If you mean "minimal triangles", as in triangles that don't have anything "inside" them when you draw the graph in the plane, then the number increases by $2$. Either way there's a mistake in your numbers.

Comment: $3n-8$ according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_network (which are the graphs constructed using Arthur's construction)

Comment: I would look at your numbers for $4$ and $5$ again. if $n = 4$ then there are $4$ possible triangles. For $n \geq 5$ it is important to know what kind of triangles you are looking for, as stated by Arthur.

Comment: If the graph is a tree, I believe this is always zero.

Comment: @PaulRichards It might be useful to note anything you have tried already

Comment: @V.Rossetto Yes, but while trees are always planar, they clearly do  not have the maximal number of triangles for their respective number of nodes (as long as $n \geq 3$).

Comment: @Arthur. Thanks to your reply, I finally understood the question. I think the OP's question is about your empty triangles, because for $n=5$, he finds $4$ (he probably  missed the "second" one because of a particular drawing, but would have counted the "big" one that he could not miss). Therefore, I would say $t_n=2n-5$.

Answer (score -1):

I will suppose you are only counting triangles with no nodes inside.  Let's also suppose both that the graph is completely triangulated so there are no polygons with more edges on the inside and that the nodes are not colinear previnting triangles(otherwise we could create more triangles).

Suppose there are $t$ triangles in total, $e$ edges, and $n$ nodes or vertices.  Suppose that of these, $p$ nodes and edges are on the outer boundary.  Then we have:

$$t+n=e+1$$ $$3t=2(e-p)+p$$

These give $t=2n-2-p$.  But $p \ge 3$ for $n\ge 3$ so $$\max(t) = 2n-5.$$

For $n=5$,   $\max(t) = 5$ not $4$

Comment: Thanks for the clear statement of my assumptions.  You are correct about the n=5 case (I have amended the question).  I will have a look at your answer when I get home from work.

Comment: Have you gotten home from work yet?