# Number of triangles in a planar graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Assume that G = (V, E) is a planar graph. If G has 8-vertices and 13
edges then what can be a minimal possible number of triangular regions?
What can be a maximal possible number of triangular regions?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676312/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-triangles-in-a-planar-graph-with-n-vertices

Comment: @Elaqqad thanks, but that question didn't really have the constraints on edges mine had, nor did it cover the minimum triangles

Comment: When you say "triangular region", do you mean complete subgraphs of three vertices?

Answer (score 1):

The Euler formula tells us that $G$ has $7$ faces. Let $T$ be the number of triangles, therefore each of the remaining $7-T$ faces is not a triangle.

We now do the standard counting of edges by faces. We have $T$ faces with $3$ edges and $7-T$ faces with $4$ or more faces. Therefore our count is at least $3T+4(7-T)$. As usual, we next realize that we counted each edge twice. So our count is $2*13$.

Therefore
$$2*13 \geq 3T+4(7-T)=28-T$$

This proves that $T \geq 2$.

The graph must have at least $2$ triangles.

Now, as Perry Elliott-Iverson pointed, $7$ is not possible (as the dual graph would have an odd number of odd vertices). So $2 \leq T \leq 6$. All those can be shown possible.